# How to solve this ordinary differential equation $tx'''+3x''-tx'-x=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For equation $tx''' +3x''-tx'-x=0$, we know a special solution $x_1=\frac{1}{t}$, how to general solution?

I firstly attempted $d(tx''+2x'-tx)=0$,then $tx'' +2x' -tx = C$,$C$ is a constant.But in next step , I found that my solution is wrong.Since $x_1=\frac{1}{t}$ is a special solution of $tx''' +3x''-tx'-x=0$,we found $x_2 = -\frac{1}{t}$ is a solution of equation.Then $x = x_1-x_2 =\frac{2}{t}$ is a solution of $tx''+2x'-tx=0$.As you can see ,the step is wrong.

Then I attemped other way to solve this equation ,but all failed.Could help me solve this equation?Thans!

Comment: Let $x(t)=\frac{y(t)} t$ and everything becomes simple.

Comment: @Trivial: Did you try Reduction of Order?

Comment: Yeah,I reduced one order by  making up the difference.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici :I still can't solve the equation.At the first ,I want to use formulation $y = C_1y_1 + C_2y_1\int \frac{1}{y_1^2}e^{-\int p(x)dx}\quad dx$,if we know a solution of equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y=0$,then use method of variation of constant,we can solve this equation.But I can find one solution of $tx''+2x'-tx=0$ by special solution $x_1=\frac{1}{t}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [*Reduction of Order*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order), we have

$$tx''' +3x''-tx'-x=0, ~~~~x_1 = \dfrac{1}{t}$$

Let

$$x_2 = v~ x_1 = \dfrac{v}{t}$$

Taking derivatives, substituting and simplifying into $tx_2''' +3x_2''-tx_2'-x_2=0$

$$v''' - v' = 0$$

Let $w = v'$, so we have

$$w'' - w = 0 \implies w = a e^t + b e^{-t}$$

This gives

$$v = a e^t + b e^{-t} + c$$

From the initial substitution

$$x_2 = \dfrac{v}{t} = \dfrac{a e^t + b e^{-t} + c}{t}$$

Comment: Ohhhhhh!But I still have a problem.Why we assumed $x_2 = vx_1=\frac{v}{t}$?

Comment: What do you mean? That is the Reduction of Order method - see the link or https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/ReductionofOrder.aspx for theory.

Comment: I mean is that why we supoose another solution $x_2 = vx_1$.We don't other solvtions and their fomulation.

Comment: Reduction of order is a technique for solving second-order linear ordinary differential equations. It is used when one solution is known and a second linearly independent solution is desired. You are given $x_1$ and want a second solution, so using this method, you assume a second linearly independent solution of $$x_2 = x_1~ v = \dfrac{v}{t}$$ This is all developed as part of the theory of this method.

Comment: Oh!I know.We didn't study this solution.Thanks for your sharing and solution.

Comment: Sorry,I forgot acception.